# How to keep form error message blank on initial load in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms

I'm trying to learn forms in AngularJS 1.x.  But I have error messages that are always on when it first loads.  How to develop behaviour such that they are blank on load, and only red after a submit if fields were not entered?  Seems to be a few states I have to use the built-in directives for.

[image]

All the elements are similar so let's just take apart this bit.  Also if different for a radio and dropdown list maybe we can discuss that too.

```
<p>First Name:<input type="text" id="firstName" ng-model="firstName" required/>
    <span style="background-color: red" ng-if="identification.firstName.$error.required">The first name is required.</span>
</p>
```

Do I chain a few directives with || or && ?

Behaviour I'm aiming for

1. How to keep the error messages off when it loads?
2. when I hit submit, and a field is blank, will it then activate the css red error messages?
3. I'd like the error messages to clear as I fill in the form without reloading.

Yeah, so any tips greatly appreciated.  Doesn't have to be particularly pretty

Thanks

---

***UPDATE 1***

[gist of current code](https://gist.github.com/urbanware/f343c72665c5ac81b769c5c24c1e430a)

Well I took a stab at it.  Still really a hot mess at this point.  Don't know how to use submit to test for each field and then display the error message if blank.  Also seems like a lot of duplication on the testing of field states. Is there a better way to break up that logic? Ugggghhhhh

***UPDATE 2***

This one's weird, the form now has all text boxes not buttons or checkboxes!? But the HTML hasn't changed.  Sigh

[image: what did i do?]

Answer (score 0):

```
    ng-if="identification.firstName.$error.required && !$pristine"
```

Go search more on $pristine and $dirty validator

Answer (score 0):

You can add some other property to your ng-if and set its value to true only when form is submitted.

in your html add this new property

```
<p>First Name:<input type="text" id="firstName" ng-model="firstName" required/>
    <span style="background-color: red" ng-if="identification.firstName.$error.required && running">The first name is required.</span>
</p>
```

in your controller set this property to true when form is submitted

```
$scope.submit = function(){
    $scope.running = true;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try later today

Comment: Not sure how to use your $scope.submit , so I've added a gist of code I'm working on

Comment: submit function is where you submit your form in your case inside your update function <input type="button " value="Submit " ng-click="update(identification) " />

Comment: in your case it is your apply function